# project with TabBar CRASHED when opened

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.2

I have an project using tab bar controller. Recently when i opened the project, "Internal Error" prompt out, crashing xcode. Anyone have idea on how to tackle it?

```
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-933/IBPlugin/WidgetIntegration/IBUITabBar/IBUITabBar.m:118
Details:  This item isn't in this tab bar.
Object:   <IBUITabBar: 0x402284780>
Method:   -frameForItem:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x40010a260>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
0  0x00000001080df366 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
1  0x00000001077561a4 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
2  0x000000010b9afafa (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
3  0x000000010b9efeeb (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
4  0x000000010b1f999c -[NSObject(IBFrameworkObjectIntegration) ibVisibleRectForChild:inFrameController:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
5  0x000000010b9e2584 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
6  0x000000010b9effe3 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
7  0x000000010b2113e5 -[IBEditorCanvasFrameController clippedRectForObject:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
8  0x000000010b212a16 -[IBEditorCanvasFrameController objectsFromBackToFrontAtPoint:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
9  0x000000010b212af3 -[IBEditorCanvasFrameController objectAtPoint:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
10  0x000000010b228d91 -[IBViewEditorCanvasFrameController trackMeasurementsWithEvent:atPoint:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
11  0x000000010b228f19 -[IBViewEditorCanvasFrameController sendEvent:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
12  0x00007fff86d0452a -[NSWindow sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
13  0x00007fff86c9c3a5 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
14  0x0000000107fe7a11 -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
15  0x00007fff86c32682 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
16  0x00007fff86eb180c NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
17  0x00000001076e5eec (in Xcode)
```

Comment: put a breakpoints to know where exactly this problem happened then show us your code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have properly connected all IBOutlet & delegate, datasource.